# Timepicker no funciona

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timepicker

estoy ocupando este [timepicker](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker) pero no funciona, supongo que debería funcionar con una directiva con angularJS, el cual también lo estoy ocupando

```js
$('#timepicker5').timepicker({
  template: false,
  showInputs: true,
  minuteStep: 5
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12" data-ng-if="mnCtrl.movimientoConfig.horaOperacionMostrar">
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="mnCtrl.valid.horaOperacion?'has-'+mnCtrl.valid.horaOperacion:''">
    <label for="horaOperacion" class="control-label"> <i class="fa"
                data-ng-class="mnCtrl.valid.horaOperacion?(mnCtrl.valid.horaOperacion ==='success'?'fa-check':'fa-times-circle-o'): ''"></i>
            Hora
        </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
        <input id="timepicker5" type="text" class="input-small">
        <i class="icon-time"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basado en la experiencia personal usar componentes jquery con AngularJS trae muchisimos dolores de cabeza y finalmente solo los he usado en caso expecificos (1 vez en 3 annos). Le recomiendo usar https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker.

La libreria con todos los componentes es https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#top y la verdad es muy buena libreria y me ha resuelto 99% de mis problemas. Pero si aun prefiere usar los componentes jQuery mi recomendacion es que cree Directivas que encapsulen sus componentes, y en esas directivas use el lenguaje jqLite que es la forma segura de AngularJS usar jQuery de esta manera esta evitando lickeos de memoria.

Espero estas ideas le sirvan.